# How to prevent direct access to files in folder?

Tags: php

A have a webpage with separated *"subdir"* with this structure:

- ***mywebpage***

  - */subdir/system/* - here are php forms files,
- *index.php*

The index.php calls file1.php in /system. Then other files in /system are called by "submits".
I can't write correct *.htaccess* to prevent calling these */system/* directly by their URLs.

I have googled and tried various *.htaccess* contents. But mostly either the *"subdir"* wasn't accessible at all (even not from *index.php*) or the *"webpage"* access returned **"404"**.

Normally a user shall open the *index.php* and decide what he wants to do. Depending on this, he is redirected to respective */system/*.php.
Any other try / e.g. adding [https://mywebpage/subdir/system/](https://mywebpage/subdir/system/%3Canyfile%3E)*anyfile*. shall redirect him back to index.php or any other "Error page".

Comment: The typical way is to define a global constant in the entry point (like index.php) a file that is ran before anything else, then check in each file if that constant is defined `if(!defined('SOME_CONST')) die ("No direct access");`

Answer (score 2):

The typical way is to define a global constant in the entry point (like index.php) a file that is ran before anything else, then check in each file if that constant is defined

```
 define('SOME_CONST', true);
```

Then at the top of each file

```
if(!defined('SOME_CONST')) die ("No direct access");
```

Therefor accessing the file without first loading the file that defines the constant results in termination of PHP.

This "constant" can be anything, typically I use a base path that is relative to the index.php file etc....

```
    define('MY_BASE_PATH', __DIR__.'/');
```

And so on...

**A few things to keep in mind**

I should mention you should not define it in a file and include it in your other files, it wont work that way.

```
   //DO NOT DO THIS as IT wont WORK!!!!! - technically it never fails
  //--- in the file somefile.php ---

  //required file defines SOME_CONST
  require 'index.php'; 
  //define('SOME_CONST', true); -- defined in index.php, think of it like copy and pasting that files code at this spot.

  //will never fail, because it's defined by the file included/required above
  if(!defined('SOME_CONST')) die ("No direct access");
```

It's like putting this in your code and expecting it to fail (obviously, here it will never fail):

```
  //dont do this either
  define('SOME_CONST', true);
  if(!defined('SOME_CONST')) die ("No direct access");
```

Instead do it this way:

So you have to include the files from that entry point, and use something like a router etc... basic MVC.  Do this instead (vastly simplified)

```
 // --- in index.php ---
define('SOME_CONST', true);

require 'somepage.php';
//if(!defined('SOME_CONST')) die ("No direct access"); included in the above require
```

And then

```
//--- in somefile.php ---
if(!defined('SOME_CONST')) die ("No direct access"); //will fail if index.php is not loaded.
```

So if someone goes to just that `somefile.php` the constant is not defined.  Because the `index.php` was not executed "BEFORE" this file....  UNLIKE if you include the `index.php` (in `somefile.php`) before the check. You Obviously cannot include it (`index.php`) after the check.  So it must be ran before `somefile.php` and NOT when ONLY `somefile.php` is loaded.  Which is why you can't include `index.php` in `somefile.php` but instead must include `somefile.php` in `index.php`.

Also obviously you will need more then just one page `somefile.php`.  So in index you will need a way to direct the request to the proper page.  This is called routing.  And is a whole other topic...

I tried to keep it as basic as possible.  It's really quite simple.

Enjoy.

Comment: Something is wrong or I didn't understand everything correctly.

Comment: `Something is wrong` - that doesn't help me.  You have to be more specific.

Comment: If you use the last 2 code blocks, put one in `index.php` the other in `somefile.php` (both files in same folder) and then try to access `index.php` (should work) and then  access `somefile.php` by its self you should get the error message.

Comment: With *define('ACCESS', true);* in index.php and *  require 'index.php';  //defines SOME_CONST
  if(!defined('ACCESS')) die ("No direct access");* in /system/go.php
I get **"500"**

Comment: you did add the `<?php` tag in the file(s), right?  Sorry I have to ask.

Comment: Changed:
added *<?php define('DIRECT_ACCESS', true); * in */system/access.php*
and
*<?php
require 'access.php';  //defines SOME_CONST
if(!defined('DIRERCT_ACCESS')) die ("No direct access");
?>*
in */system/somefile.php*
Resulting in *"No direct access"* running both from *index.php* and by direct call *localhost:8888/mywebpage/system/somefile.php*

Comment: I said specifically not to do it that way, if I read that right.  Why not post an update to the question so I can properly read that?  `I should mention you should not define it in a file and include it in your other files, it wont work that way` and you put `<?php require 'access.php'; if(!defined('DIRERCT_ACCESS')) die ("No direct access"); ?>`  Which is exactly what I said no to do, but in anycase it should always work (in this case) not fail.

Comment: Also you spelled this wrong `DIRERCT_ACCESS` should be `DIRECT_ACCESS` as in `if(!defined('DIRERCT_ACCESS')) ... `  Which is why it fails all the time....  Now if I could read that properly it would have been easier.  In comments use the backtic  (the tilde key ~, without the shift) to do code like this `code`